# Regexp for matching "A not(B) C' - excluding middle match

Tags: regex

I want to match '|| C \n' in the following string:

```
|| A || B || C \n
```

With a regexp that is something like '\|\|not(\|\|).*?\n', so that all '||' are excluded except the last one.

How does one do this?

Comment: You are asking for [`\|\|(?:(?!\|\|).)*?\n`](https://regex101.com/r/4utNDQ/1). But probably, you may also use `\|\|(?:(?!\|\|).)*$` or `\|\|(?!.*\|\|).*`.

Comment: @Peter - `all '||' are excluded except the last one` Did I answer your question ? Or, was the last 3 bars ok with you per strubnutz https://regex101.com/r/4utNDQ/2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just look for 2 bars, then make sure no other double bars exist.
Have to protect against a *triple bar* `|||` first.

`\|\|(?!\|)[^|]*(?:\|(?!\|)[^|]*)*$`

Readable version

```
 \|\|                          # Double bar
 (?! \| )                      # Cannot be a third bar
 [^|]*                         # Optional non-bars
 (?:                           # Cluster
      \|                            # Bar
      (?! \| )                      # if not followed by bar
      [^|]*                         # Optional non-bars
 )*                            # End, optionally 0 to many times
 $                             # EOS
```